# Logstash - read and parse a string with multiple records on same line

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Below is my config file,

```
input {
file{
    path => "/Users/.../Work/Projects/ELK/Logstash/Input/*.txt"
    start_position => beginning
    codec => "json"
    type => "data"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
   }
}

filter { 
    grok { match => { "message" => "<%{NUMBER}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP} %{IPV4} %{HOSTNAME:nodeName}: %{NUMBER} %{WORD} \[%{DATA}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:[anotherField]} \n" } }
        # Create array of strings
        mutate { split => { "[anotherField]" => "| " } }
        # Create a separate event for each array entry
        split { field => "[anotherField]" } 
    }

output {
stdout{}
 file {
   path => "/Users/...../Work/Projects/ELK/Logstash/test.csv"
   codec => line { format => "%{nodeName},%{anotherField}"}
 }
}
```

Input to the above is:

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-12-01T13:30:00.004Z","message":"<190>Dec  1 14:29:59 10.62.161.199 AA-AMG3U: 0950198238 NN [MDA 8/4]: LN44 SA 2022 Dec  1 14:29:59:87 CET 17 4001 10.XX.133.XX 56560 401 91.235.10.25 15179 2400160261XXXXX_467000XXXX1_35292011220XXXXX_string1 | LN44 SD 2022 Dec  1 14:29:59:89 CET 17 4001 10.XX.133.XX 56560 401 91.235.10.25 15179 2400160261XXXXX_467000XXXX1_35292011220XXXXX_string2 | LN44 SA 2022 Dec  1 14:29:59:87 CET 17 4001 10.XX.133.XX 56560 401 91.235.10.25 15179 2400160261XXXXX_467679XXXX2_35292011220XXXXX_string1 \n","@version":"1","host":"100.62.161.XXX"}
```

Current output is:

```
AA-AMG3U,LN44 SA 2022 Dec  1 14:29:59:87 CET 17 4001 10.XX.133.XX 56560 401 91.235.10.25 15179 2400160261XXXXX_467000XXXX1_35292011220XXXXX_string1 
AA-AMG3U,LN44 SD 2022 Dec  1 14:29:59:89 CET 17 4001 10.XX.133.XX 56560 401 91.235.10.25 15179 2400160261XXXXX_467000XXXX1_35292011220XXXXX_string2 
AA-AMG3U,LN44 SA 2022 Dec  1 14:29:59:87 CET 17 4001 10.XX.133.XX 56560 401 91.235.10.25 15179 2400160261XXXXX_467679XXXX2_35292011220XXXXX_string1
```

How do I change to get the output as:

```
AA-AMG3U,LN44,SA,2022 Dec  1 14:29:59:87 CET,17,4001,10.XX.133.XX 56560,401 91.235.10.25 15179,2400160261XXXXX,467000XXXX1,35292011220XXXXX,string1 
AA-AMG3U,LN44,SD,2022 Dec  1 14:29:59:87 CET,17,4001,10.XX.133.XX 56560,401 91.235.10.25 15179,2400160261XXXXX,467000XXXX1,35292011220XXXXX,string1 
AA-AMG3U,LN44,SA,2022 Dec  1 14:29:59:87 CET,17,4001,10.XX.133.XX 56560,401 91.235.10.25 15179,2400160261XXXXX,467000XXXX2,35292011220XXXXX,string1
```

I am not sure how to iterate through arrays that are inside a specific string?